# What is the max length for Google Cloud "Studio" Voices?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am using the Google Cloud Studio Voices: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/wavenet#studio_voices_preview

Just curious does anyone know what the max length for transcription is? I see they are "preview" status

Answer (score 1):

This is following the Cloud text to speech's [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas). (Which is per byte).

I believe the [Preview](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) mentioned here is the release state of the feature, which indicates it may have limited support for it.

Also additionally for you're reference you can see [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing) for this feature here.